# Choosing right technology (SVG vs Canvas)

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, raphael

I'm writing an app for shape manipulation, such that after creating simple shapes the user can create more complex ones by clipping the shapes against each other (i.e. combining two circles together into a figure 8 stored using a single path rather than a group, or performing intersection of two circles to create a "bite" mark), and am trying to decide on a graphics library to use.

SVG seems to handle 80% of the functionality I need out of the box (shape storage, movement, rotation, scaling). The problem is that the other 20% (using clipping to create a new set of complex polygons) seems impossible to achieve without recreating SVG functionality in my own modules (I'd have to store the shape once for drawing inside SVG, and once for processing clipping myself). I could be wrong about SVG, but by reading about Raphael library (based on SVG), it seems like it only handles clipping using a rectangle, and even that clipping is temporary (it only renders part of the shape, but still stores entire shape to be rerendered once the clipping rectangle is moved). Perhaps I'm just confused about SVG standard, but even retrieving/parsing the paths to compute a new path using subsets of previous paths seems non-obvious in SVG (there is a Subpath() function, but I don't see anything to find the points of intersection of two polygon perimeters, or combine several subpaths into a single path).

As a result, Canvas seems like a better alternative since it doesn't introduce the extra overhead by keeping track of shapes I'd already have to keep track of to make my own clipping implementation work. Not only that, I've already implemented the polygon class that can be moved, rotated, and scaled. Canvas has some other issues, however (I'd have to implement my own redraw method, which I'm sure will not be as efficient as SVG one that takes advantage of browser-specific frameworks in Chrome and Firefox; and I'd have to accept IE incompatibility which is handled for free with libraries like Raphael).

Thanks

Comment: excanvas adds canvas support to IE6/7/8 - http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/

Answer (score 2):

This may address what you're mentioning.

Clipping can be done using non-rectangular objects using the 'clipPath' element.

For example, I have element with id of 'clipper' that defines what to clip out, and a path that is subject to the clipping.  Not sure if they intersect in this snippet.

```
<g clip-rule="nonzero">
  <clipPath id="clipper">
    <ellipse rx="70" ry="95" clip-rule="evenodd"/>
  </clipPath>

  <!-- stuff to be clipped -->
  <path clip-path="url(#clipper)" d="M-100 0 a100 50"/>
</g>
```

This is just a snippet from something I have.  Hope it helps.

Comment: More examples can be seen in the svg testsuite, starting from http://dev.w3.org/SVG/profiles/1.1F2/test/harness/htmlObject/masking-intro-01-f.html and onwards (all the tests named masking-*)

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me that you are trying to do 2D constructive geometry.  Since SVG runs in retained mode, the objects you draw are stored and then the various operations performed.  With Canvas you are running against a bit map so the changes are effected immediately.  Since your users will in turn perform more operations on your simpler shapes to create ever more complex ones Canvas should in the long term be a better fit.

The only outstanding question is what will be done with those objects once your users are finished with them.  If you zoom the image it will get the jaggies.  SVG will avoid that problem but you trade-off with greater complexity and performance impact.

Answer (score 2):

Both svg and canvas are a  vector graphical technology.Each one having some different functionality.

Canvas

Canvas is a bitmap with an immediate modegraphics application programming interface (API) for drawing on it. Canvas is a “fire and forget” model that renders its graphics directly to its bitmap and then subsequently has no sense of the shapes that were drawn; only the resulting bitmap stays around.

More Information about canvas - http://www.queryhome.com/51054/about-html5-canvas

SVG

SVG is used to describe Scalable Vector Graphics

SVG is known as a retained mode graphics model persisting in an in-memory model. Analogous to HTML, SVG builds an object model of elements, attributes, and styles. When the element appears in an HTML5 document, it behaves like an inline block and is part of the HTML document tree.

More Information about SVG - http://www.queryhome.com/50869/about-svg-part-1

[image: svg vs canvas]

See here for more information about canvas vs svg in detail - [Comparing svg vs canvas](http://www.queryhome.com/65020/importance-of-svg-and-canvas-in-html5)

Answer (score 1):

You're right - you'll have to mathematically perform the clipping and creation of new shapes regardless of whether you use SVG or Canvas.  I'm biased, it seems like it would be more useful to use SVG since you also get things like DOM events on the shapes (mouse, dragging) and serialization into a graphical format for free.